# Not able to successfully run npm install on Mac Air (M2)

Tags: npm-install

After migrating files from my old Mac to a new Mac Air (Sonoma 14.2.1, Apple M2), I haven't been able to do a simple npm install. I've deleted node_modules in my project, cleared npm cache and even reinstalled npm (node v21.6.1). There were no errors during installation. But when testing the install with "npm -v", it does not re-build node_modules, and it displays the following error:

```
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1152
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '../lib/cli.js'
Require stack:
- /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:990:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1237:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js:2:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1378:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1437:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1212:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js' ]
}
```